# Relationship queries in a three-way PivotTable

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, relationship

I had the task of working with a three-sided summary table, but I can not get all the properties and their values for a particular product.

I have three models **Product**, **Property** and **PropertyValue**.

Model **Product**:

```
    public function properties() :BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class,'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_id')
                ->with('values')
                ->withPivot('property_value_id')
                ->orderBy('order');
        }
    
    public function values() :BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(PropertyValue::class,'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_value_id');
        }
```

Model **Property**:

```
    public function products() :BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this
                ->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_property', 'property_id', 'product_id');
        }
    
        public function values() :BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(PropertyValue::class, 'product_property','property_id','property_value_id')->withPivot('product_id');
        }
```

Model **PropertyValue**:

```
    public function properties() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'product_property','property_id','property_value_id');
    }
    
    public function products() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_property','property_value_id','product_id');
    }
```

Pivot table migration **product_property**:

```
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('product_property', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreignId('property_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreignId('property_value_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            });
        }
```

I can get **Product** and then get either its properties **Property**

```
$product->properties
```

or only the values of its **PropertyValue** properties

```
$product->values
```

However, I can't get the chain:

```
Product->This property->The values of these properties for the selected product.
```

If I do something like

```
$product->properties()->first()->values
```

then I get all the **PropertyValue** selected **Property** in the pivot table, not for the specifically selected **Product**.

My task is complicated by the fact that I cannot make any changes to the database.
Please tell me how to get a chain without changing the pivot table

```
Product->This property->The values of these properties for the selected product.
```

Comment: Please provide a json or array like output example on how `Product`, `Property` and `PropertyValue` interconnect. Is `PropertyValue` mandatory for `Property` or can it exist without `Property` and be solely connected with `Product`. Because your `BelongsToMany` id relations do not make sense.

Comment: Also, have you tested the chain with `properties.values`, e.g by lazy loading a `Product` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$property = $product->properties()->first();
$values = $property->values()->where('product_id', $product->id)->get();
```

Or like this :

```
$property = $product->properties()->first();
$values = $property->values()
->join('product_property', 'product_property.property_value_id', '=', 'property_values.id')
->where('product_id', $product->id)
->get();
```